# Redirect 301 - why is my old url being appended to my new url causing a 404 error?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```
Redirect 301 /features/blahblah.php http://www.mysite.com/articles/blahblah1.php
```

results in http://www.mysite.com/articles/blahblah1.php?q=features/blahblah.php which is a 404 error page not found.

So what am i doing wrong here

Comment: in related news, can someone provide me with a good resource for htaccess related stuff like ^ (.*) etc...

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect documents exactly what's happening.

You probably want to use RedirectMatch, something like:

```
RedirectMatch ^/features/blahblah.php http://www.mysite.com/articles/blahblah1.php
```

If you want it to be a "permanent" redirect with HTTP status 301 (which can be desirable for SEO purposes) rather than a temporary 302 redirect, then instead use:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/features/blahblah.php http://www.mysite.com/articles/blahblah1.php
```

Comment: RedirectMatch permanent ^/features/blahblah.php http://www.mysite.com/articles/blahblah1.php results in the same http://www.mysite.com/articles/blahblah1.php?q=features/blahblah.php