# Why are all my other 301 redirects working except these 2? (NOT a query string)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've got a list of over 100 redirects, nearly all of which seem to be working except for two. I'm using the common format for a htaccess 301 redirect:

```
redirect 301 /shop/category.cfm/wall-decals http://wallcandyarts.com/wall-decals.html
```

Near as I can tell, there's nothing wrong this one. The ones I'm having problems with are these two:

```
redirect 301 /shop/product.cfm/chalkboard-wall-panels http://wallcandyarts.com/chalkboard-decals/chalkboard-panels.html
redirect 301 /shop/category.cfm/chalkboard-decals http://wallcandyarts.com/chalkboard-decals.html
```

I've read about problems with query strings, but that's not the case here. I also saw when assembling this list of redirects that if the new path ended in "/" that it would cause it to get a similar result of what it's getting with the redirects above. For example, clicking http://www.wallcandyarts.com/shop/product.cfm/chalkboard-wall-panels will give you a "mashed" URL, and I don't know why. Any thoughts?

This is my first foray into anything this heavy with htaccess that didn't involve simply copy/paste, so forgive my ignorance here. Hoping to learn a lot.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is the entire htaccess. A lot of stuff that was there prior to me adding 301 directs. The code I added starts at line 181.

http://pastie.org/2371768

Comment: I assume you are using Apache, so I added the "apache" tag.

Comment: I checked the answers listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623225/redirect-301-why-is-my-old-url-being-appended-to-my-new-url-causing-a-404-error) but they didn't work, either. Unless I'm just flat doing it wrong.

Comment: Should be migrated to serverfault.com

Comment: @Micah I've responded to your comment on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess. You have a rule before those two redirects that is rewriting "shop" to "wall-decals.html" and as such the two redirects which aren't working aren't even being reached.

I could take a much better guess if you posted the full htaccess file though.

Comment: thanks for the tip - I moved the line for "shop" to the last line, but that didn't fix it. I've updated to include a link to the entire .htaccess file.

Comment: I've just looked at your site again and those two links appear to be redirecting correctly.